# erratic results from go exec cmd

Tags: go

I am making my first steps in Go. I have a cli command that, for the time being, just drop and recreate a DB with go and Postgres dropdb + createdb tools.

The following code produce inconsistent results. The checkout function print or do not print the "out" bytes variable.

I am suspecting some race condition and that I should use pointers somewhere instead of passing values to the same function.

Is this code that bad ?

```
func ensurepath(command string) string {
    ensuredcommand, LookErr := exec.LookPath(command)
    if LookErr != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%v is not found", command)
    }
    log.Printf("ensure path for command '%v' : %v", command, ensuredcommand)
    return command
}

// warning : cmd error message is also a "out" value, it is not in err
func checkout(err error, out []byte) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("command error %v : %s", err, out)
    } else {
        log.Printf("command result %T : %s", out, out)
    }
}

var restore = cli.Command{
    Name:    "restore",
    Aliases: []string{"r"},
    Usage:   "restore backup",
    Action: func(c *cli.Context) error {
        cmdArgs := "devdb"
        dropDB := ensurepath("dropdb")
        createDB := ensurepath("createdb")

        outErrDrop, err := exec.Command(dropDB, cmdArgs).CombinedOutput()
        checkout(err, outErrDrop)

        outErrCreate, createErr := exec.Command(createDB, cmdArgs).CombinedOutput()
        checkout(createErr, outErrCreate)

        return nil
    },
}
```

**EDIT**

Example of weird output

If I comment the lines corresponding to the "createDB" part, meaning I only drop the db I have a consistent and expected output.

```
var restore = cli.Command{
    Name:    "restore",
    Aliases: []string{"r"},
    Usage:   "restore backup",
    Action: func(c *cli.Context) error {
        cmdArgs := "devdb"
        dropDB := ensurepath("dropdb")
        //createDB := ensurepath("createdb")

        outErrDrop, err := exec.Command(dropDB, cmdArgs).CombinedOutput()
        checkout(err, outErrDrop)

        //outErrCreate, createErr := exec.Command(createDB, cmdArgs).CombinedOutput()
        //checkout(createErr, outErrCreate)

        return nil
    },
} 
//output
2018/02/19 15:49:44 ensure path for command 'dropdb' : /usr/local/bin/dropdb
2018/02/19 15:49:44 command error exit status 1 : dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  database "devdb" does not exist
```

But if introduce back the lines corresponding to the createdb part (exactly as my first code block above) I have the following result :

```
2018/02/19 15:53:11 ensure path for command 'dropdb' : /usr/local/bin/dropdb
2018/02/19 15:53:11 ensure path for command 'createdb' : /usr/local/bin/createdb
2018/02/19 15:53:11 command result []uint8 :
2018/02/19 15:53:11 command result []uint8 :
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with this. Are you sure the commands are producing output? Do you get any output at all?

Comment: What is the actual output your program produces? Perhaps dropdb and createdb don't output anything on success ("no news is good news").

Comment: @AndySchweig, I edited my question to provide output. My feeling is some race condition issue but tI have double check and the way I write my command it is expected the result of the command before proceeding to next lines.

Comment: @Peter question edited with outputs (since when I only can mention one perosn on stackoverflow ? weird)

Comment: And what makes you think that this output is wrong? Does the database exist after you run your program? What output do you expect?

Comment: I am feeling really stupid right know. 
I think I was so focused on being wrong, missing something with those new Pointers concept (for me) I didn't even see the obvious : it works. So it does output anything. The dropdb ou createdb tools does not output anything in case of success.

Comment: Really sorry for the waste of time

Comment: I guess I'll have to recreate a stackoverflow account with an other name and avatar